# Shifted hlines in tblr tabular in RTL context

Tags: luatex, expl3, tabularray, right-to-left

I'm trying to test tblr tabular provided by `tabularray` package  in an RTL context by adding `\textdir TRT` (lualatex engine), everything looks fine except for this issue  shown in this example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\textdir TRT 
\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{|c|}
\hline
one\\
\hline 
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

The output appears fine, but if you take a great zoom the following defect can be seen ( horizontal lines cross the left side of the table )

[image]

With double vlines the defect becomes greater, hlines are shifted more to the left

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\textdir TRT
\begin{document}

a%
\begin{tblr}{|c||}
\hline
one\\
\hline 
\end{tblr}%
b
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Remark**

Tabular must be in RTL context not enclosed in LTR group so second column must be on the left of the first column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue come from `\mathdir`, `tblr` use `\vcenter` command  like standard tabular environment so basically we are in math mode in the beginning of the tabular, and the mathdir is TLT  we need to change it to TRT for tabular in right to left context.

The math direction needs to be restored inside tabular cells (math direction in RTL context is always LTR), this can be done with `\SetTblrInner{cells={preto={\mathdir TLT}}}` (thanks to @UdiFogiel)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\AddToHook{env/tblr/begin}{%
\ifnum\textdirection=0\else \mathdir TRT\fi
}

\SetTblrInner{cells={preto={\mathdir TLT}}}

\begin{document}

Hello\par
\begin{tblr}{|c||c|||}
\hline
one & two \\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\textdir TRT 

Hello\par
\begin{tblr}{|c||c|||}
\hline
one & two $ax+b$\\
\hline
\end{tblr}

$ax+b$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find the root of the problem, but you might be satisfied with enclosing the tabular in LTR group and reverse the horizontal order of the cells (internally, not typing them in reverse, and the cells themselves would still be RTL).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter

\bool_new:N \__tblr_RTL_bool
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__tblr_split_one_line:nn #1 #2
{
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { & } { #2 }
    \bool_if:NTF \__tblr_RTL_bool
    { 
        \seq_reverse:N \l_tmpa_seq 
    }
    { }
    \int_set:Nn \c@rownum {#1}
    \int_zero:N \c@colnum
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
    {
        \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { ##1 }
        \__tblr_remove_braces:N \l_tmpa_tl
        \__tblr_trim_par_space_tokens:N \l_tmpa_tl
        \int_incr:N \c@colnum
        \__tblr_extract_table_commands:N \l_tmpa_tl
        \bool_if:NTF \__tblr_RTL_bool
        { 
            \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_tmpa_tl { } {\tl_put_left:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \textdir TRT } }
        }
        {  }
        \__tblr_trim_par_space_tokens:N \l_tmpa_tl
        \__tblr_spec_gput:neV { text } { [#1][\int_use:N \c@colnum] } \l_tmpa_tl
    }
    \bool_lazy_all:nTF
    {
        { \int_compare_p:nNn {#1} = {\c@rowcount} }
        { \int_compare_p:nNn {\c@colnum} = {1} }
        { \tl_if_empty_p:N \l_tmpa_tl }
    }
    { \int_decr:N \c@rowcount }
    {
        \__tblr_prop_gput:nnx
        {row} { [#1] / cell-number } { \int_use:N \c@colnum }
        \int_compare:nT { \c@colnum > \c@colcount }
        {
            \int_set_eq:NN \c@colcount \c@colnum
        }
    }
}

\cs_set_protected:Npn \__tblr_environ_code:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
{
    \group_align_safe_begin:
    \int_gincr:N \g__tblr_table_count_int
    \tl_set:Nn \l__tblr_env_name_tl {#1}
    \mode_if_math:TF
    { \bool_set_true:N \l__tblr_math_mode_bool }
    { \bool_set_false:N \l__tblr_math_mode_bool }
    \str_if_eq:eeTF { TRT } { \lua_now:n { tex.print(tex.textdir) } }
    { 
        \bool_set_true:N \__tblr_RTL_bool
        \textdir TLT
    }
    { }
    \__tblr_builder:nnn {#2} {#3} {#4}
    \group_align_safe_end:
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\pagedir TRT \bodydir TRT \pardir TRT \textdir TRT
\begin{document}

    \begin{tblr}{|c|c|}
        \hline
        one & two\\
        \hline 
    \end{tblr}

\begin{tblr}{|c|c||}
    \hline
    one & two\\
    \hline 
\end{tblr}%

\end{document}
```

With the above code all the horizontal coordinates related to inner specification will be reversed, e.g. in the second tabular the double vlines are on the right and not on the left. I believe it can be fixed too, but i found this behavior more convenient.

### Remark

I think the problem is related to the `leftpos`, `rightpos`, `abovepos` and `belowpos` Inner specification keys, see how they affect the examples you gave

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\textdir TRT 
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tblr}{hlines={rightpos=0},vlines={abovepos=1}}
        one\\
    \end{tblr}
    
    
        a%
        \begin{tblr}{colspec={|c||},hlines={rightpos=0},vlines={abovepos=1}}
            one\\
        \end{tblr}%
        b
    \end{document}
\end{document}
```

maybe the function `\__tblr_get_hline_left_right_skips:nnn` is the cause for this problem.

### Edit

I wanted to add a few things to Salim Bou's great solution. Instead of using hooks, we can patch the command `\__tblr_environ_code:nnnn` to test the text direction, this way we won't need to hook the test `\ifnum\textdirection=0\else \mathdir TRT\fi` for each environment defined via `\NewTblrEnviron`. It can be done with

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__tblr_environ_code:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
{
    \ifnum\textdirection=0\else \mathdir TRT\fi % <<< new
    \group_align_safe_begin:
    \int_gincr:N \g__tblr_table_count_int
    \tl_set:Nn \l__tblr_env_name_tl {#1}
    \mode_if_math:TF
    { \bool_set_true:N \l__tblr_math_mode_bool }
    { \bool_set_false:N \l__tblr_math_mode_bool }
    \__tblr_builder:nnn {#2} {#3} {#4}
    \group_align_safe_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Another observation is that a Tblr with the outer property `long` is not using math mode, as can be seen in the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    
    
    \pagedir TRT \bodydir TRT  
    
    Hello\par
    \begin{longtblr}{|c||c|||}
        \hline
        one & two $ax+b$\\
        \hline
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

But it needs `\pagedir` and `\bodydir` to be `TRT` to typeset in RTL.

A final note is that using `\SetTblrInner[tblr,longtblr]{cells={cmd={\mathdir TLT}}}` will fail if the cell is warped with more than a couple of braces, for example in the following table the direction of the equation is wrong

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}


\AddToHook{env/tblr/begin}{%
\ifnum\textdirection=0\else \mathdir TRT\fi
}

\SetTblrInner{cells={cmd={\mathdir TLT}}}

\begin{document}

\textdir TRT 

Hello\par
\begin{tblr}{|c||c|||}
\hline
one & {{{two $ax+b$}}}\\
\hline
\end{tblr}

$ax+b$

\end{document}
```

Hence it might be better using `\SetTblrInner{cells={preto={\mathdir TLT}}}`, or again we can patch things up so we won't have to add the inner specification to each environment defined with `\NewTblrEnviron` with the following

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter

\cs_set_protected:Npn \__tblr_split_one_line:nn #1 #2
{
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { & } { #2 }
    \int_set:Nn \c@rownum {#1}
    \int_zero:N \c@colnum
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
    {
        \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { ##1 }
        \__tblr_remove_braces:N \l_tmpa_tl
        \__tblr_trim_par_space_tokens:N \l_tmpa_tl
        \int_incr:N \c@colnum
        \__tblr_extract_table_commands:N \l_tmpa_tl
        \__tblr_trim_par_space_tokens:N \l_tmpa_tl
        \tl_if_empty:NF \l_tmpa_tl {\tl_put_left:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \mathdir TLT } } % <<< new
        \__tblr_spec_gput:neV { text } { [#1][\int_use:N \c@colnum] } \l_tmpa_tl
    }
    %% Decrease row count by 1 if the last row has only one empty cell text
    %% We need to do it here since the > or < column type may add text to cells
    \bool_lazy_all:nTF
    {
        { \int_compare_p:nNn {#1} = {\c@rowcount} }
        { \int_compare_p:nNn {\c@colnum} = {1} }
        { \tl_if_empty_p:N \l_tmpa_tl }
    }
    { \int_decr:N \c@rowcount }
    {
        \__tblr_prop_gput:nnx
        {row} { [#1] / cell-number } { \int_use:N \c@colnum }
        \int_compare:nT { \c@colnum > \c@colcount }
        {
            \int_set_eq:NN \c@colcount \c@colnum
        }
    }
}

\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: For columns type `|c|c||` double vlines should be on the left side (same order as columns) like this:  
 || wot |  eno |

Comment: @SalimBou, It depends on your perspective on how things "should" be... As I stated I find it more natural that if I specify a double vlines on the right, they would appear on the right side, they are the same order as the columns specification, as I pointed out in my answer with the above code the cells index remain as if you type the tabular in LTR. I will try to reverse the index as well.

Comment: Thanks for the correction  about `longtblr` environment  and for patchs, the only baffling thing is why `cmd=\mathdir TRT` work fine inside cells warped with two  braces and do not work with those wraped with three braces !

Comment: @SalimBou Thank you for finding the root of the problem! It seems to be intentional (and related to to the `cmd` option, not to `\mathdir` ), see https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/90 . It is also documented, though it hidden as a comment in the source code (see the definition of `\__tblr_get_cell_text_real` in page 117 of the documentation). There might better locations for the patchs, but I will leave that for the developer :)